# Unable to get IAP products with live App, While It is working fine with Sandox Accounts?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am using MKStoreKit in swift projects to Implement IAP. I have tested it with sandbox users it is working fine. But With Live app I am unable to get the even products.

Is there is any updating in IAP implementation??

Comment: Try logging out from settings and provide your actual apple account?

Comment: Which url are you using for production IAP ?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Saheb Roy

But We logged In with actual account but Issue is until same.

Comment: Maulik Bhuptani I'm using this url for Live App(Production) https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt